# IBM Knowledge Studio and workspace for invited user

Tags: ibm-server

I have an IBM Knowledge Studio project.
Now I invited users to join me as human annotators.

But when the user connects to Knowledge Studio he only sees a blank screen titles "Workspaces" and the information:
"A workspace is not yet created for you. Ask the person who invited you to participate to create a workspace and assign a task to you. Learn more"

I somehow cannot get this to work.
What am I missing?

Best, Adrian